# Angularjs ng-repeat track by $index not working

Tags: angularjs

I have custom directive that is using `controllerAs` and binding an external controller. The controller function is to render the list in the html under an input box. Earlier this controller was with in the directive, it was not bound to directive and every thing was working fine and `ng-reapeat` was showing the list and list was tracked by $index so not duplicates were shown. But since the time I have moved the controller outside directive the track by `$index` have stopped working it showing me the duplicates in list.

What's missing ? Do I need to define index in controller or use it as `controller.$index`?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)